# Can't install Android NDK (ndk-bundle) in Android Studio: failed to mkdirs

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-ndk, windows-7

I am setting up Android development environment on my Windows 7 running machine. I installed Android studio 3.3 and other required packages.

while trying to install Android NDK I get following error:

[image]

I downloaded NDK bundle from the above highlighted link and tried to extract the .zip file manually  but it also gives error as:

! C:\Users[UserName]\Downloads\android-ndk-r18-windows-x86_64.zip: Cannot create folder C:\Users[UserName]\Downloads\android-ndk-r18\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\test\std\input.output\stream.buffers\streambuf\streambuf.protected

Access is denied.

! C:\Users[UserName]\Downloads\android-ndk-r18-windows-x86_64.zip: Cannot create folder C:\Users[UserName]\Downloads\android-ndk-r18\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\test\std\input.output\stream.buffers\streambuf\streambuf.protected\streambuf.put.area

The system cannot find the path specified.
.
.
.
.
.
.

I have the Admin rights on the machine and I also tried to manually make a folder named 'streambuf.protected' in the directory and it gives me error as 'Access Denied' but I can make a folder with any other name.

What can be the cause of this and how can I install the Android NDK successfully ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found out that my Oraganization is using McAfee VirusScan Enterprise. The Access Protection task  has User-Defined rule as **Cryptolocker - Extension protected** which blocks from creating this folder.

I found more info on it here:
https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?id=KB50998&page=content&pmv=print